# raspberry pi - canbus can-utils timeout?

Tags: raspberry-pi, can-bus

I'm using raspberry PI with MCP2515 + the canbus-utils.

My raspberry pi is working on battery - so when I switch on the car&power up the PI - everything is working.

But when I switch off the car, then try to switch on after 1 hour I get no replay from the canbus-utils, and I need to restart the can service.

Any idea why?

Does the canbus-utils has some kind of TImeout? that can be change\ignore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the PI is the only member on the bus the controller switch to bus_off state, because nobody is acknowledging the messages send and the message will otherwise be send indefinitely, to protect for bus overload of the retransmissions.

Also there was a version of the kernel a couple of months ago wich not recovered from some error condition. 
The latest version of the kernel has this fixed.

use sudo rpi-update to get the latest kernel.

Also at the initialisation script of your CAN bus add the following

```
ip link set can0 type can restart-ms 100
```

Comment: OK , I will give it a try :-) ........................    and then I could leave the PI on for all time , and when I will turn on the car I will get the data ? so my code will not need to do restart? - did I understand you correct?   BTY you know what is version should be?       - Thanks ,

Comment: $ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.14.52-v7+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611)) #1123 SMP Wed Jun 27 17:35:49 BST 2018
So at least 4.14.52

Comment: Updated answer to point out that I had a restart timer on the can devices set.

Comment: 2 question about your replay - what does this line do ?ip link set can0 type can restart-ms 100 , and do I have to upgrage the PI for it?      --> Thanks ,

Comment: from [link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt)

 "restart-ms 100"
 Automatic restart delay time. If set to a non-zero value, a
 restart of the CAN controller will be triggered automatically
 in case of a bus-off condition after the specified delay time
 in milliseconds. By default it's off.

Comment: Thanks , I will check it -    Thank you for the help!